# Regarding xcode 3.2.2 &iPhone SDK up to 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am developing ipad application am using these developmental environments

xcode 3.2.6,ios 4.3 but i need following environment

Prerequisites
Supported platforms include:

Mac OS X Leopard (Macbook or iMac), 
Xcode 3.1.2 Mac OS X Snow Leopard (Macbook or iMac),
 Xcode 3.2.2 
iPhone SDK up to 3.1.3

please can any one tell me  i can get those softwares.thanks in advance :p

Answer (score 0):

Where I work we keep old versions of iOS on our devices, because you can't download old versions of iOS from Apple. At least that's what my colleague told me and I believed him.

Could you tell me what it is that you're trying to do that doesn't work with 4.3?